# Email Alert Recipient Related User Addition

Tags: lookup, email-alert

How do I add a Related User to the object, or related records, from which an email alert is coming from? For example, I have a custom lookup field on the User object named Opportunity Approver. What I'd like to do is use this Opportunity Approver lookup of Users on the User object from an Opportunity Email Alert.

So, I'd like an email alert generated that gets sent to the Opportunity Owner's Opportunity Approver from their User record. How do I accomplish this? Thank you.

Comment: one workaround - add a field of type EMAIL on Opportunity and populate with process buildwer, workflow or trigger with the `Opportunity.Owner.Opportunity_approver__r.email` value

Comment: Thank you, but I'd like to use the User Lookup, rather than the email transposed to that area. Any other advice?

Comment: @crop1645,Error: Field Opportunity does not exist. Check spelling.

Comment: Tamim -- My comment was speculative on the syntax as I wasn't exactly sure what your data model was. If you edit your post to define the exact data model you are using, it will be easier to give a more definitive response

Comment: I got it to work. However, I'd still like to see a true solution that let me look into the User record of the Opportunity Owner to populate a lookup of Opportunity Approver. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce Email Alerts on Opportunity, will, OOB, give you these options:

[image]

If you click Owner, you aren't given any additional lookups out of the Owner SObject (`User` in your situation)

So, if you wish to continue with Email Alerts there are a few options

**Option 1**

- Create a field of type Email on Opportunity
- Populate it by either trigger, workflow field update, or process builder field update. You want to ensure that the field is refreshed before the email alert is triggered because subordinates become bosses or get new bosses and hence any value initially populated in the custom Email field could get stale

[Option 1 is covered in this well-received Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrYuAAK) that is worth voting on. [See also this SFSE question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42188/email-alerts-and-formula-lookup-fields)

**Option 2**

- Use an `Email_proxy__c` custom object that you populate with all the    necessary information for the template's merge fields. This would also include a custom field of type Email (or perhaps several such fields)
- The proxy object can be populated by Process Builder or a trigger
- You then have workflows/process flows on the proxy object

The proxy object has some interesting use cases beyond yours - such as when you want to send a lot of emails out in a general way and avoid some apex outbound messaging governor limits